# Crash while copying a vector to another

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I have a function. In this I am trying to copy a structure to another structure of same type. This structure is stored as a vector in `CProjectData` class.
When I try to copy contents, it crashes. Piece of code is shown below:

```
void CProjectData::send()
{
    struct  EmuComputerData tempStruct;

//ignore this line
m_pClient->GetTeleSend()->CreateHeader(GetFbMsgType(m_dwCmdId));
//ignore this line
CProjectData* pProjectdata = (CProjectData*) m_pClient->GetTeleSend()->AddBuffer(sizeof(CProjectData));
//ignore this line
pProjectdata->m_wErrorCode = m_wErrorCode;
//ignore this line
strcpy_s(pProjectdata->m_szProjectName, MAX_PROJECTNAME_LENGTH + 1, m_szProjectName);

vector<struct EmuComputerData>::iterator iter;
iter = m_emuComputerData.begin();
for (; iter != m_emuComputerData.end(); iter++)
{
    tempStruct.wEmuComputerNo = (*iter).wEmuComputerNo;
    tempStruct.dwIPAddress = (*iter).dwIPAddress;
    tempStruct.wPCCount = (*iter).wPCCount;

    vector<WORD>::iterator apIter;
    apIter = (*iter).apNumbers.begin();
    for (; apIter != (*iter).apNumbers.end(); apIter++)
    {
        tempStruct.apNumbers.push_back(*apIter);
    }
    //crashes after executing this line
    pProjectdata->m_emuComputerData.push_back(tempStruct);
}
```

}

`m_emuComputerData` is declared as

```
vector<struct   EmuComputerData> m_emuComputerData;
```

in `ProjectData` class.

This is a structure which again contains a vector.

```
 struct EmuComputerData
    {
    WORD        wPCCount;
    WORD        wEmuComputerNo;     
    DWORD       dwIPAddress;        
    vector<WORD>    apNumbers;          
    };
```

**Here is call stack: and it crashes while I tru to copy `vector<WORD>  apNumbers` . I believe I am doing something silly while copying this vector.**

```
msvcr90d.dll!operator delete(void * pUserData=0xcdcdcdcd)  Line 52 + 0x3 bytes  C++
    EmuDiagnosticsService.exe!std::allocator<EmuComputerData>::deallocate(EmuComputerData * _Ptr=0xcdcdcdcd, unsigned int __formal=0)  Line 140 + 0x9 bytes C++
    EmuDiagnosticsService.exe!std::vector<EmuComputerData,std::allocator<EmuComputerData> >::_Insert_n(std::_Vector_const_iterator<EmuComputerData,std::allocator<EmuComputerData> > _Where={wPCCount=??? wEmuComputerNo=??? dwIPAddress=??? ...}, unsigned int _Count=1, const EmuComputerData & _Val={...})  Line 1202    C++
    EmuDiagnosticsService.exe!std::vector<EmuComputerData,std::allocator<EmuComputerData> >::insert(std::_Vector_const_iterator<EmuComputerData,std::allocator<EmuComputerData> > _Where={wPCCount=??? wEmuComputerNo=??? dwIPAddress=??? ...}, const EmuComputerData & _Val={...})  Line 878   C++
    EmuDiagnosticsService.exe!std::vector<EmuComputerData,std::allocator<EmuComputerData> >::push_back(const EmuComputerData & _Val={...})  Line 823 + 0x58 bytes   C++
>   EmuDiagnosticsService.exe!CProjectData::send()  Line 574    C++
    EmuDiagnosticsService.exe!CEmuDiagTCPServer::Send()  Line 374 + 0xf bytes   C++
    EmuDiagnosticsService.exe!StartTCPServer(void * dummy=0x00000000)  Line 251 C++
```

thanks
Nipun

Comment: Is it possible that `pProjectdata` is actually  `this`?  That would mean you are pushing into the same vector you're reading from, which would cause trouble

Answer (score 2):

You probably have some prior corrupt, before the copy runs.  The pointer being deleted - 0xCDCDCDCD - is suspiciously "regular", which suggests it may be a sentinel value the compiler's somehow placed in uninitialised or already-released memory (there's a history of such values, with perhaps the most famous being 0xDEADBEEF).

It may well be that the `pProjectdata->m_emuComputerData` variable wasn't properly initialised, or has been destroyed already.  The `CProjectData` type seems suspect... `AddBuffer` doesn't seem to be type aware which implies `CProjectData`'s constructor didn't run; using a `std::string`, or `strcpy_s` for `sizeof m_szProjectName`, would be more reassuring than `MAX_PROJECTNAME_LENGTH + 1`

FWIW, `vector`s can be copied with "value semantics" as long as their contents can too, so this code:

```
vector<struct EmuComputerData>::iterator iter;
iter = m_emuComputerData.begin();
for (; iter != m_emuComputerData.end(); iter++)
{
    tempStruct.wEmuComputerNo = (*iter).wEmuComputerNo;
    tempStruct.dwIPAddress = (*iter).dwIPAddress;
    tempStruct.wPCCount = (*iter).wPCCount;

    vector<WORD>::iterator apIter;
    apIter = (*iter).apNumbers.begin();
    for (; apIter != (*iter).apNumbers.end(); apIter++)
    {
        tempStruct.apNumbers.push_back(*apIter);
    }
    //crashes after executing this line
    pProjectdata->m_emuComputerData.push_back(tempStruct);
}
```

Can be simplified to:

```
pProjectdata->m_emuComputerData.push_back(m_emuComputerData);
```

Comment: I already tried what you are suggesting in last line, but same result...Crash

Comment: @Nipun As I said, it's memory corruption beforehand, not anything to do with the copying... that code's just there - FWIW (for whatever it's worth) - as general programming feedback.  Using something like valgrind is an efficient way to search for your actual error, but putting `cerr <<` logging statements into your code to check the variables lifetimes is ok too.  Check the `CProjectData` code carefully or post the struct here for us to check.